# Postgresql doesn't display privileges of a creator. Why?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created db this way :

```
CREATE USER moderator_area_dev CREATEDB LOGIN PASSWORD 'moderator_password_area_dev_';
CREATE DATABASE moderator_area_dev WITH OWNER = moderator_area_dev CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE moderator_area_dev to moderator_area_dev;
```

after that, Im extracting privileges of my owner user, **hoping to see ALL Granted privileges**:

```
SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, privilege_type
FROM   information_schema.table_privileges 
WHERE  grantee = 'moderator_area_dev'
```

But, in fact, all i can see is empty result. Why empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the user does not have privileges on any table.

You just created the user and didn't give it privileges on any table, so what do you expect?

Even if you connected to the new database `moderator_area_dev` before checking, you would not find anything, because the database does not contain any tables yet, except

- catalog tables, which belong to the bootstrap superuser
- any objects copied from `template1`

Comment: thanks for the answer. i have some questions: 1) what is  the point of issuing Grant All Privileges command in the beginning? 2) how can i grant user privileges?

Comment: The `GRANT` statement is totally pointless, because the owner has all these privileges anyway: connect, create schemas and temporary tables. What do you mean by "user privileges"?

Comment: i want to see what privileges my user "moderator_area_dev" has

Comment: There is no easy way to see what privileges a user has. You'd have to query all objects in the database.